# graphical logfile viewer for fail2ban?

Tags: security, log-files, fail2ban

is there a GUI or other nicer way to study fail2ban logs other than command line? my Ubuntu 18.04.4 is behind a router with a range of ports forwarded, including 22 for ssh, so UFW and fail2ban are pretty important.

Collapsing repeated entries and sort and search across multiple files would be helpful.

my fail2ban logs used to grow by 1 new ban every 1 - 2 minutes. Something happened over the last 2 weeks and now it's only showing ban totals increasing every 8-10 minutes. No config changes. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

[netdata](https://www.netdata.cloud/) is the way to go. I used `sudo apt-get install` and got a really old version, 1.9.0. The `fail2ban` monitoring was not already setup.

Using their one-liner installation from their front page is the way to go. `fail2ban` is setup and monitored immediately.

So cool. I'm super impressed with `netdata`. It's open source under GPLv3 and works with stand-alone machines and containers.